# How to solve a recursive sequence that is oscillating to a limit point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, real-numbers

In class we only learned the "tools" to prove that a sequence that is monotonically increasing or decreasing converges. How to prove that a sequence converges if it is given in recursive form and is increasing at some intervals and decreasing at some intervals that are very hard to "select".
Is it even possible without the standard form?

Comment: Do you have any specific example(s) in mind?

Comment: No I don't, I just thought if it is theoretically possible @BrianM.Scott

Comment: One way is to extract a monotonic subsequence, and deduce it's limit. Then go back to the original sequence and try to bound the rate of oscillation.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one fixed answer to this question - there are many ways we can show a sequence is convergent. However, when we are working with recursively defined sequences, it is often easier to prove that the sequence is a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence).

Once we have a Cauchy Sequence, if we are working with series of real numbers, we can use the *General Principle of Convergence* which says that every Cauchy Sequence is convergent.

[This link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cauchy-sequences/) gives some really nice explanations and examples.